# How to use getSerializableExtra method from fragment?

Tags: java, android

I want to get getSerializableExtra from fragment?I got the error that "cannot resove the method getIntent()". please advice

```
@Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_activity_content, container, false);
        return view;

        ActivityInfo activityInfo =(ActivityInfo)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("name");


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

getIntent is not available for Fragments directly,you can use that using:

```
getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra("your_key")
```

From the comments:

> Unrechable Statement issue

Because you are writing that after `return view;`,anything after an unconditional return statement will be unreachable.So use it before return like:

```
getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra("your_key")
return view;
```

**Note:** While this answer might work for your case i would suggest you use the `setArgument` approach mentioned in other answers.

Comment: What error did you get when you used `getActivity()` ?

Comment: @Maur Gajra unreachable statement

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if its  a good practice to use getIntent().getSerializableExtra("your_key") inside a fragment .

however you can use   for example :  setArguments() to pass data to fragment as shown below

```
public  Fragment newInstance(){
        Fragment fragment = new MyFragment();
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(containerid, fragment);

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable("key",myobject);

        fragment.setArguments(bundle);

        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

and than override oncreate inside your fragment class to get the serialized object

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        if(getArguments()!=null){
            object= getArguments().getSerializable("key");
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you! but not worked which has a error point that "unreachable statement"

Answer (score 0):

Use the instance patter in your fragments

```
class ArgumentsFragment : Fragment() {

companion object {
    private const val SERIALIZABLE_KEY = "SERIALIZABLE_KEY"
    fun instance(data: Serializable) = ArgumentsFragment().apply {
        arguments = Bundle().apply { putSerializable(SERIALIZABLE_KEY, data) }
    }
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val serializableData = arguments?.getSerializable(SERIALIZABLE_KEY)
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_base, container)
}
```

And in your activity simply invoke it like this

```
class ArgumentsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_base)

    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(ArgumentsFragment
            .instance(object : Serializable {}),
            ArgumentsFragment.toString()).commit()
}
```

Anyway i would recomend you to use parcelable instead of serializable https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable

It is faster than Serializable and a better practice to use it.